# Monotouch addsubview animation

Tags: animation, xamarin.ios, transition, addsubview

I have my navigation controller and my view controller. I can't seem to get a simple transition between those views when I push a button in the navigation bar. It now just pops up.

When I push the button in the navigation controller, it calls the code below in the main file.

```
public void GoToViewController()
{
      window.AddSubview(theViewController.View);
}
```

I have been calling:

```
UIView.SetAnimationTransition(UIViewAnimationTransition.None, spct.View, true);
```

which works, but I would like to let this view simple appear from the right, over the other view (just like the navigation controller does with its views).

Comment: Have you considered just using a UINavigationController?  It sounds like it fits your scenario.

Comment: That is probably what I should use for the next project. But I'm to far in now, I've already created multiple viewcontrollers. Or is it possible to link those nicely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use UINavigationController.

Making the transition should be fairly easy, and is worth it over trying to recreate what Apple has already built.

For each of your view controllers, you should be able to change their base class to UINavigationController--or just change their type to UINavigationController if you did not subclass them.  After that, you should just have to replace your custom transition code to use PushViewController(), PopViewControllerAnimated(), etc.

Using UINavigationController is fairly simple in general.

Comment: Thanks alot, thought it would have been way more difficult!